# could not load type 'Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler' on apphb

Tags: appharbor, nancy

That is the errormessage when I deploy a website project to appharbor.

And have no idea where to start looking...

Any push in the right direction would be great, thanks!

More details:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler'.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +9671464
   System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetTypeWithAssert(String type) +38
   System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetHandlerType(String type) +13
   System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type) +19
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +86
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +262
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, I've thrown stuff on apphb before with no issues at all. I suspect you may be missing some dependencies since its running on Mono, not IIS.